# RegEx to replace a specific letter from string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I need a RegEx to replace all occurrences of "l" by "ł" in string.
Replacement should happen only if:

1) There is `z` before `l`,

AND

2) There should be a number or `.` after `l`

For ex:

1) If string is `abc zl12,200`, output should be `abc zł12,200`.

2) If string is `zl.00`, output should be `zł.00`.

3) If string is `adbc zlopr`,  output should be `adbc zlopr`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a expression like this.

**[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HbNDux)**

```
string output = Regex.Replace(str, @"(z)l(\d+|\.)", "$1ł$2");
```

- (z) will look for z and identified by $1
- l is the character you want to replace with ł
- (\d+|.) is for number or dot `.`, it is identified by $2

`()` is used to make segments and we used `$1` and `$2` to get the segments and produce the output string along with replaced character.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `look around` assertions.

**Regex**: `(?<=z)l(?=\d|\.)`

**Explanation**:

`l(?=\d|\.)` this part will match for a `l` followed by a `digit` or a period `.`

`(?<=z)` will see if `l` is preceded by `z`.

So your code will be

`string output = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=z)l(?=\d|\.)", "ł");`

**<kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fB2qW1/1)</kbd>**  **<kbd>[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/fgm9D2)</kbd>**